# how to read a music in a voice channel using discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I'm coding a bot for my discord server and as it'said in the title i'm tring to play a music in a voice channel using the VoiceConnection.play method.
But I'm always catching this error : 'TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int'.

Here's my code :

```
const Command = require("./command");

module.exports = class Play extends Command {

    static match (message) {
        console.log("checking play");
        return message.content.startsWith("!play");
    }

    static action (message) {
        let voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type === "voice").first();
        voiceChannel.join()
            .then(connection => {
                connection.play(ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlAU_w7-Xp8', { quality: 'highestaudio' }));
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }
}
```

and here are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.0.2",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^4.0.1",
    "opusscript": "0.0.7",
    "ytdl-core": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

the full error message :

```
TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int
TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int

C:\Users\Charly\Desktop\henallux\bloc3\bot\node_modules\opusscript\build\opusscript_native_wasm.js:8
var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};var moduleOverrides={};var key;for(key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}Module["arguments"]=[];Module["thisProgram"]="./this.program";Module["quit"]=function(status,toThrow){throw toThrow};Module["preRun"]=[];Module["postRun"]=[];var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var 
ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof process.versions==="object"&&typeof process.versions.node==="string";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=ENVIRONMENT_HAS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var scriptDirectory="";function locateFile(path){
abort(TypeError: Cannot convert "null" to int). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
```

Comment: From the surface, it looks like `ytdl` can't convert the video to a stream, or can't find it. Were there any other errors in the console?

Comment: I modified the first message and put the entire error message

Comment: Try using `@discordjs/opus` rather than `opusscript` per the comments on [this issue](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3895).